# How to open First time Launch page after detecting first launch?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am codeing a IOS GAME application not a single view or blank view ..

Ok so i am trying to first detect the first launch witch i am able to do with no problem by puting this code in my appDelagate.swift

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:      [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


// Override point for customization after application launch.

let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey:     "launchedBefore")

if launchedBefore{
print("Has launched before")

}
else
{
print("First launch")


}

return launchedBefore
}
```

ok now how do i accualy use this code to open a certain menue screen just the one time?? i can not find a answer anywhere.. 
my gameViewControler.swift looks like this where everytime the app runs this "FirstMainMenuScene" opens.. however i want it to only open on the first lauch and otherwize opeh just the plain old "MainMenuScene"

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()




    // Load 'GameScene.sks' as a GKScene. This provides gameplay  related content
    // including entities and graphs.
    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
        // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'

        let scene = FirstMainMenuScene(size: CGSize(width: 1536, height: 2048))

    // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

        // Present the scene
        view.presentScene(scene)


        view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        view.showsFPS = true
        view.showsNodeCount = true
```

now i have tried everything i can think of here such as putting an if statement and counting the number of times the app opened with a 
"var numberOfRuns = 0"
and then puting a counter in like
"numberOfRuns += 1"
then doing if statements like
"if numberOfRuns >= 1{ //open the first page i want// else{ // open the accual app page"
but i took that all out because it did not work
so my question is .. how do i implement this detect first run code that i put in the appDelaget.swift????
someone please help me i have been stuck for hours !!!!!

Comment: On first launch, you then need to set UserDefaults true for the "launchedBefore" key.

Comment: ok i will put on here
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "launchedBefore")
but then how do i open a page on the first view only?? i still dont know how to use this

Comment: ok SOLVED!!! the problem was with the appDelagate.swift.. i compleety left it default and put the dectect first run code in the main storyboard.swift
i think it is beacuse i picked GAME and not blank activity!

Answer (score 0):

ok SOLVED!!! the problem was with the appDelagate.swift.. i compleety left it default and put the dectect first run code in the main storyboard.swift i think it is beacuse i picked GAME and not blank activity! here is the code if anyone comes after me and needs help!!!
import UIKit
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "launchedBefore")
    if launchedBefore{
        print("Has launched before")
        // Load 'GameScene.sks' as a GKScene. This provides gameplay related content
        // including entities and graphs.
        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'

            let scene = MainMenuScene(size: CGSize(width: 1536, height: 2048))

            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)


            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true


        }
    }
    else
    {
        print("First launch")



        // Load 'GameScene.sks' as a GKScene. This provides gameplay related content
        // including entities and graphs.
        if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
            // Load the SKScene from 'GameScene.sks'

            let scene = FirstMainMenuScene(size: CGSize(width: 1536, height: 2048))

            // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
            scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

            // Present the scene
            view.presentScene(scene)


            view.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

            view.showsFPS = true
            view.showsNodeCount = true
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "launchedBefore")
        }



    }
```